# Container resizing according window resize

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a window witch is resizing on creationcomplete phase according user preference.
This part woks well.
But inside this window a s:Group (maincontainer2) exists and even if width and height is in percent, the s:Group size is bigger that the new window measure.

I try to solve that with percentheigt and percentwidth but no result.
If somebody know how to solve that, I'll happy to read.

Thanks a lot

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<windowSkin:wCustomWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                          skinClass="fr.interis.ui.windowSkin.CustomWindowSkin"
                          resizable="true"
                          creationComplete="wcustomwindow1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                          preinitialize="wContactPat_loadServices(event)"
                          xmlns:windowSkin="fr.interis.ui.windowSkin.*" 
                          minWidth="400" minHeight="300" 

                          xmlns:customNavTab="fr.interis.component.customNavTab.*" 
                          xmlns:componentGlob="fr.interis.ui.componentGlob.*">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Placer ici les éléments non visuels (services et objets de valeur, par exemple). -->
        <s:HTTPService id = "phpContactPat"
                       fault = "serviceFault(event)"
                       method="POST"
                       resultFormat="e4x"
                       result = "resultContactPat(event)"/>
    </fx:Declarations>


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import fr.interis.config.urlManager;
            import fr.interis.ui.componentGlob.IconManager;
            import fr.interis.util.DateUtility;
            import fr.interis.util.FileSerializer;
            import fr.interis.util.UserPrefs;
            import fr.interis.util.windowPlace;
            import fr.kapit.flex.ui.spark.loginBox.RetrievePasswordSkin;

            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.controls.Button;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.ItemClickEvent;
            import mx.events.ResizeEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            import spark.events.GridSelectionEvent;
            private var pg:UserPrefs;





            private function closeMyWindow():void
            {
                stage.nativeWindow.dispatchEvent(new Event("myEventClose", true));
                stage.nativeWindow.close();
            }

            private function onMyEventClose(e:Event):void
            {
                pg = new UserPrefs();
                this.pg.appPosX = stage.nativeWindow.x;
                this.pg.appPosY = stage.nativeWindow.y;
                this.pg.appWidth = stage.nativeWindow.width;
                this.pg.appHeight = stage.nativeWindow.height;
                FileSerializer.writeObjectToFile(this.pg, "prefcontactPat.up");

            }

            private function serviceFault(event:FaultEvent):void
            {
                trace("Erreur "+ event.fault.message);
            }

            protected function wcustomwindow1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                stage.nativeWindow.addEventListener("myEventClose",onMyEventClose);

                var pos:windowPlace = new windowPlace("prefcontactPat.up");
                stage.nativeWindow.x = pos.windowX;
                stage.nativeWindow.y = pos.windowY;
                stage.nativeWindow.height = pos.windowH;
                stage.nativeWindow.width = pos.windowW;  





            }



        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:VGroup paddingLeft="7" paddingRight="7" id="mainContainer" left="7" right="7" top="40" bottom="4">

        <s:HGroup width="100%" height="53" id="titleWin">

            <s:Image x="0" y="0" width="53" height="53" />

            <s:VGroup width="40%">
                <s:HGroup width="100%" height="50%">    <!-- Nom prenom-->
                    <s:Label text="{_patientNomPrenom}" id="lNomPrenom" fontWeight="bold"/>
                </s:HGroup>

                <s:HGroup width="100%" height="50%">    <!-- Naissance-->
                    <s:Label text="{_patientNaissance}" id="lNaissance" />
                </s:HGroup> 

            </s:VGroup>

            <s:VGroup width="40%">  <!-- Modif-->

                <s:Label id="ldhCrea"
                         textAlign="left" styleName="dataCreaModif"/>
                <s:Label id="ldhModif"
                         textAlign="left" styleName="dataCreaModif"/>
            </s:VGroup>

        </s:HGroup>



        <s:Group id="mainContainer2" width="100%">

            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10" 
                                  paddingTop="5" paddingBottom="15"/>
            </s:layout>
            <!-- partie centrale-->
            <s:DataGrid id="dgContactPat" fontWeight="normal" 
                        dataProvider="{xmlCollContacts}" 
                        width="100%" height="80%" selectionChange="dgContactPat_selectionChangeHandler(event)">
                <s:columns>
                    <s:ArrayList>
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="crIndex"  visible="false"/>
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="ctTTypeCorrP" headerText="Relation" />
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="crCorrespNP" headerText="Correspondant" />
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="crTSpecialiteP" headerText="Spécialité" />
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="crNumTel1" headerText="Téléphone" />
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="crTelecopie" headerText="Fax" />
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="crCodePostal" headerText="CP" />
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="crTVilleP" headerText="Ville" />
                    </s:ArrayList>
                </s:columns>
            </s:DataGrid>



        </s:Group>


    </s:VGroup>



</windowSkin:wCustomWindow>
```

the wCustomWindow

```
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                 xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009"
                 xmlns:Layout="skin.Layout.*"
                 alpha.disabledGroup="0.5">

        <fx:Metadata>
            [HostComponent("fr.interis.ui.windowSkin.wCustomWindow")]
        </fx:Metadata>



        <s:states>
            <s:State name="normal" />
            <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledGroup" />
            <s:State name="normalAndInactive" stateGroups="inactiveGroup" />
            <s:State name="disabledAndInactive" stateGroups="disabledGroup, inactiveGroup" />
        </s:states>

        <s:Rect id="backgroundRect"
                left="0"
                right="0"
                top="0"
                bottom="0"
                alpha="0"
                >
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor alpha="0"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <s:Group bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
                 top="0" >
            <!--Fond de la fenetre-->
            <s:Rect bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
                    top="0"
                    radiusX="8" radiusY="8" >
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor color="#656565" alpha=".7" />
                </s:fill>
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#666666" />
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Rect>

            <s:Group height="38" id="moveArea"
                     left="0" right="0">

                <!--Barre bleu avec filet-->
                <s:Rect  height="25" left="10" right="10" top="10">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:SolidColor color="#055a90" />
                    </s:fill>
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:SolidColorStroke color="#666666" />
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Rect>



                <s:BitmapImage id="icon"
                               left="5" verticalCenter="0" />

                <s:Label id="titleDisplay"
                         styleName="swindowTitle"
                         left="60" top="18" verticalAlign="middle"
                         />

                <!--Zone de bouton-->

                <s:HGroup right="12" verticalCenter="0">

                    <s:Button id="btMinimize" buttonMode="true"
                              skinClass="skin.components.MinimizeButtonSkin"/>

                    <s:Button id="btMaximize" buttonMode="true"
                              skinClass="skin.components.MaximizeButtonSkin"/>

                    <s:Button id="closeButton" buttonMode="true"
                              skinClass="skin.components.CloseButtonSkin"/>

                </s:HGroup>

            </s:Group>

            <!--Fond de la zone principale-->

            <s:Rect id="background" left="10" top="35" right="10" bottom="10">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:LinearGradient rotation="-90">
                        <s:GradientEntry color="#edf0f7"/>
                        <s:GradientEntry color="#fcfbfb" />
                    </s:LinearGradient>
                </s:fill>
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="#666666" />
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Rect>

            <!--Zone dans laquelle les elements vont se positionner-->

            <s:Group id="contentGroup" left="15" right="15" top="43" bottom="15" minWidth="0"
                     minHeight="0" 
                     width.disabled="100%" height.disabled="100%"
                     width.disabledAndInactive="100%" height.disabledAndInactive="100%"
                     width.normalAndInactive="100%" height.normalAndInactive="100%">

            </s:Group>



            <s:Button height="14" id="btResize" width="14"
                      bottom="0" right="0"
                      skinClass="spark.skins.spark.windowChrome.GripperSkin" 
                      buttonMode="false"/>

        </s:Group>

    </s:SparkSkin>
```

and the host component

```
package fr.interis.ui.windowSkin
{
    import flash.display.NativeWindowDisplayState;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowSystemChrome;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowType;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.NativeWindowBoundsEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    import flashx.textLayout.elements.BreakElement;

    import mx.core.IUIComponent;
    import mx.core.IVisualElementContainer;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;
    import mx.events.ResizeEvent;
    import mx.managers.WindowedSystemManager;

    import spark.components.Group;
    import spark.components.Label;
    import spark.components.Window;
    import spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase;
    import spark.effects.Resize;
    import spark.primitives.BitmapImage;

    [Event(name="creationComplete", type="mx.events.FlexEvent")]


    public class wCustomWindow extends Window//NativeWindow//
    {

        private var _systemManager:WindowedSystemManager;
        private var _window:IVisualElementContainer;

        [SkinPart(required = "false")]
        public var btMinimize : ButtonBase;

        [SkinPart(required = "false")]
        public var btMaximize : ButtonBase;

        [SkinPart(required = "false")]
        public var btResize:ButtonBase;

        [SkinPart(required = "false")]
        public var closeButton:ButtonBase;

        [SkinPart(required = "false")]
        public var icon:BitmapImage;

        [SkinPart(required = "false")]
        public var moveArea:Group;

        [SkinPart(required = "false")]
        public var titleDisplay:Label;


        private var _iconSource:Object;
        private var _resizeCorner:String = "BR";
        private var _titleLabelText:Label;

        public function wCustomWindow()
        {
            super();    

            // Set window properties
            this.systemChrome = NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE; //car sinon pas d'affichage du menu sous windows
            //this.transparent = true;
            this.type = NativeWindowType.UTILITY;
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownListener);
        }



        private function windowResizeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            // prise en compte de la valeur mini
            UIComponent(_window).height = stage.stageHeight;
            UIComponent(_window).width = stage.stageWidth;
        }



        public function get iconSource():Object
        {
            return _iconSource;
        }

        public function set iconSource(value:Object):void
        {
            _iconSource = value;
            if(icon)
                if(icon.source!=value)
                    icon.source=value;
        }

        public function get titleText():String
        {
            return _titleLabelText.text;
        }

        public function set titleText(value:String):void
        {
            _titleLabelText.text= value;
        }

        protected override function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void
        {
            super.partAdded(partName, instance);

            switch(partName)
            {
                case 'icon':
                {
                    icon.source = _iconSource;
                    break;
                }

                case 'titleDisplay':
                {
                    //titleDisplay.text = _titleLabelText.text;
                    break;

                }
                case 'moveArea':
                {
                    moveArea.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMove);
                    break;
                }

                case 'btResize':
                {
                    btResize.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startResize);
                    btResize.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,removeResize);
                    btResize.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,removeResize);
                    btResize.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,removeResize);

                    break;
                }

                case 'btMinimize':
                {
                    EventDispatcher(instance).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, minimizeW);
                    break;
                }

                case 'btMaximize':
                {
                    EventDispatcher(instance).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, maximizeW);
                    break;
                }

                case 'closeButton':
                {

                    closeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeWindow);

                    break;
                }

            }
        }





        protected override function partRemoved(partName:String, instance:Object):void
        {
            super.partRemoved(partName, instance);

            switch(partName)
            {
                case 'moveArea':
                {
                    moveArea.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startMove);
                    break;
                }

                case 'btResize':
                {
                    //EventDispatcher(instance).removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startResize);
                    btResize.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startResize);
                    break;
                }

                case 'btMinimize':
                {
                    EventDispatcher(instance).removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,minimizeW);
                    break;
                }

                case 'btMaximize':
                {
                    EventDispatcher(instance).removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,maximizeW);
                    break;
                }
                case 'closeButton':
                {
                    closeButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,closeWindow);

                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        protected function maximizeW(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.nativeWindow.displayState == NativeWindowDisplayState.MAXIMIZED?stage.nativeWindow.restore():stage.nativeWindow.maximize();
        }

        protected function minimizeW(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.nativeWindow.minimize();
        }

        private function keyDownListener (e:KeyboardEvent):void {

            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE) {
                stage.nativeWindow.dispatchEvent(new Event("myEventClose", true));
                stage.nativeWindow.close();
            }
        }

        protected function closeWindow(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.nativeWindow.dispatchEvent(new Event("myEventClose", true));

            stage.nativeWindow.close();

        }

        protected function startMove(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.nativeWindow.startMove();
        }

        protected function removeResize(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            btResize.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startResize);
            btResize.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, startResize);

        }
        protected function startResize(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(stage.nativeWindow.resizable)
            {
                stage.nativeWindow.startResize(_resizeCorner);

                btResize.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,removeResize);
                btResize.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, startResize);

                updateDisplayList(stage.nativeWindow.width,stage.nativeWindow.height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think try setting, mainContainer2 height="100%" if that doesn't work by itself maybe you need to manually trigger an invalidateSize() and validateNow() on it after you assign the native window size, not entirely sure though why that wouldn't automatically cause an invalidation of it's children (perhaps something to do with it using a BasicLayout or absolute layout so it doesn't consider the children sizes? not sure).  Also I would experiment with using percentage sizes for the outer mainContainer and see if something about doing the layout based on left right values is causing a problem, if so you can probably just wrap it all in another group and apply those paddings to it's layout.

Comment: I try both method but none works. If you have another idea? Thanks

Comment: Is this project at an early enough stage that you could post the code in it's entirety (like do a release from Flex include source then post that somewhere).  I think if I were to have my hands on the project it'd be much easier to find out what's going wrong, part of the problem with answer this question is I'm not sure what your CustomWindow is doing or if there's other tweaks to layout or otherwise that are causing problems.

Comment: If you can't post the whole project could you localize this file and related ones paste them into a new project then export that so I can reproduce without a ton of work?